# My list type in haskell

Tags: function, haskell, types, functional-programming

I try to create an own list type in haskell but, my implementation contains errors. 
What is the proper way to do this nice. Please explain me a bit.
Thank you.

My code:

```
data List a = EmptyList | ListElement a (List a) 

instance (Show a) => Show (List a) where
        show = showList'

showList' EmptyList = showString "[]"
showList' (ListElement a EmptyList) = show a
showList' (ListElement a b) = show a ++ show " " ++ showList' b
```

Error code:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( tipusok.hs, interpreted )

tipusok.hs:12:39:
    Couldn't match expected type `Prelude.String -> Prelude.String'
                with actual type `[Char]'
    Expected type: ShowS
      Actual type: Prelude.String
    In the return type of a call of `show'
    In the expression: show a
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
showList' EmptyList = showString "[]"
```

The type of `showString` is `String -> ShowS`. `ShowS` is a type synonym for `String -> String`, so the result of `showString "[]"` is the function that prepends the string `"[]"` to its argument. Since you gave no type signature, that equation determines what type is inferred for the function, but the other equations don't match that type.

You probably wanted simply

```
showList' EmptyList = "[]"
```

Answer (score 4):

Your composition of `show` functions is incorrect. I think you mean to interpolate values.

```
showList' (ListElement a b) = show a . showChar ' ' . show b
```

should be something like:

```
showList' (ListElement a b) = show a ++ " " ++ showList' b
```

Comment: thanks, this recursive call is mandatory, i made an edit with the new error message

Comment: `showChar` does not return a `String`. I think you mean to use a whitespace literal?